# Question about the definition of a tangent plane and its non existence at a point of non differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

When a scalar field $f: S \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $\textbf{a}$, and $f(x, y) = c$ is a level surface of this function, we can prove that $\nabla f(\textbf{a})$ is perpendicular at $\textbf{a}$ to every curve lying on this level surface passing through $\textbf{a}$.
The tangent vectors at $\textbf{a}$ of this family of curves determine a plane with $\nabla f(\textbf{a})$ as a normal vector- and we call this plane a tangent plane.

This is what I've concluded is the definition of the tangent plane to a surface at a point $\textbf{a}$- if you consider the family of curves $\textbf{r}(t)$ lying on this surface passing through $\textbf{a}$, and the tangent vectors $\textbf{r}'(t)$ at $\textbf{a}$ lie on the same plane, this plane is termed the tangent plane.

Correct me if I'm wrong. I haven't found a definition of a tangent plane which didn't involve talking about differentiability.

Such a tangent plane will exist if $f$ is differentiable at $\textbf{a}$, but how do we show that such a plane will not exist if $f$ is ***not*** differentiable at $\textbf{a}$ (if we stick to the 'definition' of a tangent plane I've given above)?

Comment: "*I haven't found a definition of a tangent plane which didn't involve talking about differentiability*" Peano gave such a definition in the late 1880s. See **Definition 2** on p. 10 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1332). I'm not sure if this will help with your specific concern, however.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro
Interesting definition. Is that equivalent to this one? That paper looks interesting- I'm trying to understand the relationship between tangency and differentiability, but none of my texts go into it at all.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what kind of pathological properties are possible for a "surface", and so I'm not sure whether talking about the existence of curves lying on the surface and passing through **a** that have tangents at **a** is more restrictive than the property in the Peano definition. Maybe the surface is too "multi-directionally and radially cornered" at **a** to even have a curve through **a** with a tangent at **a**, but the Peano version still works?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you. Now that I realize it, even for smooth surfaces I don't think I'd be able to show rigourously that such a curve does indeed exist. Nor do I know what properties a surface should have at a point for there to be such a curve.